# Display results on keyup event and values inside form how to?

Tags: jquery, keyup, jquery-calculation

How do i display the output on keyup event rather than on submit and also the values inside the input fields?

I tried readonly `<input  id="result" name="totalamount" value="" readonly/>`but its not working. can someone helo?

Here is thew complete codes

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#myForm').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var actualprice = Number($("#actualprice").val().trim());
        var discount = Number($("#discount").val().trim());
        var shipping = Number($("#shipping").val().trim());

        var discountRate = (100 - discount) / 100;
        var result = (actualprice * discountRate) + shipping;

        $("#result").html("Result :" + result.toFixed(2));
    });
</script>


<form id="myForm">
    <input id="actualprice" type="number" placeholder="Actual Price">
    <input id="discount" type="number" placeholder="Discount">
    <input id="shipping" type="number" placeholder="Shipping">
    <input  id="result" name="totalamount" value="" readonly/>
    <h3 id="result"></h3>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `keyup` event for `input` and you are using same `id` `result` for an `input` and `h3`. I've changed the `id` of `h3` to `result2`.

```js
$('input').on('keyup input', function () {
  var actualprice = Number($("#actualprice").val().trim());
  var discount = Number($("#discount").val().trim());
  var shipping = Number($("#shipping").val().trim());

  var discountRate = (100 - discount) / 100;
  var result = (actualprice * discountRate) + shipping;
  
  $("#result").val("Result :" + result.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
    <input id="actualprice" type="number" placeholder="Actual Price">
    <input id="discount" type="number" placeholder="Discount">
    <input id="shipping" type="number" placeholder="Shipping">
    <input id="result" name="totalamount" value="" readonly />
    <h3 id="result2"></h3>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: sorry that h3 i do not require i wanted the results displaying inside the <input id="result" name="totalamount" value="" readonly />

Comment: thanks but when i submit the form no results in array on php print_r() function?  really appreciate your kindness

Comment: There is no action in your form. Btw I don't know `PHP`. @Seeker

Comment: sorry my bad u r right. its working like a charm <form id="myForm" method="post"> thanks alot :-)